# How to limit an Android app to thousands of specific devices

Tags: google-play-store, gmail

I want to install a single-purpose app on a thousand of devices of the same model.

**The need** :

1. The app shall not be public therefore accessible to anyone
2. The app shall be installed on my 1.000 devices. Note that the devices are the same model (let's say nexus 10) but I do not want to grant access to all nexus 10 around the world
3. It shall be as easy as possible. I can imagine for example logging in these 1000 device with a single account and then limiting ditribution to that account, but it's quite long and might as well not be possible (limitation to the number of devices an account can have)
4. The app shall be updatable on all devices simultaneously
5. The number of devices might grow to 2.000 or even **OVER 9.000**

Comment: Can't you put the app on the app store but the first screen is a login were you only distribute the password to those whom you allow. You could also have a mechanism were at login people request access and you then can great them access from the admin side.

Comment: It's a good idea and I actually did it but that won't do because I would have to manually log in in each and every devices and People can still download it and rate my app 0 star with a legit "wtf is this" therefore killing my brand.

Comment: First of all nobody will download an app that is reserved if you make it clear in it's description. There are millions of useless apps but I don't download them and don't care. As for logging, you could have a database to do it automatically. There is no need for anything manual.

Comment: Another solution is to host the app SDK on you website instead of the play store. People with the link can download it. (You have to enable `Trust unknown sources` in security settings)